# Force batch file to wait for his own process

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to force command line to wait for his own process, because this process app.exe must finish, and takes some time. I use artificial timeout to prevent script from closing, because if I set the timeout wrong, then app.exe gives wrong results. I have problem with correct estimate timeout.

I read something about options /w and /k but I don't know where it insert.
Maybe wait for process would be good solution, but I don't know how can I do it.
Code is below:

```
( 
@echo instruction1 to app.exe
@echo instruction2 to app.exe
@echo instruction3 to app.exe
@echo instruction4 to app.exe
timeout 3
) | app.exe > out.txt
```

This script is called from another application written in c++ but not from app.exe. I have windows 7.
The line which run script:

`system("script.bat");`

Answer (score 0):

you may use *start* command to make a batch script wait for itself

```
@echo off

if /I "%~1" EQU "runme" goto %~1

start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "%~s0 runme %*"

exit /B

:runme

( 
@echo instruction1 to app.exe
@echo instruction2 to app.exe
@echo instruction3 to app.exe
@echo instruction4 to app.exe
) | app.exe > out.txt

timeout 3

exit /B
```

> **EDIT**: may I misunderstood your question, perhaps this is what you're asking for

```
start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "app.exe some_parameter_here"
start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "app.exe some_parameter_here"
start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "app.exe some_parameter_here"
...
```

or

```
start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "echo some_parameter_here | app.exe"
start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "echo some_parameter_here | app.exe"
start "" /B /WAIT cmd /c "echo some_parameter_here | app.exe"
...
```